# Mathematical places to visit

Tags: soft-question, big-list

There are certain buildings and places on this planet where mathematicians can find delight because of the history, the art, the architecture, and for other reasons.  For example, the Alhambra with its heavy use of geometric patterns.  Or, perhaps, going to the leaning tower of Pisa and playing games with calculating where its shadow will be cast.  Clearly, there are many places with historical or related significance to those interested in mathematics.  I would enjoy hearing about some from people here -- in particular, I would love to hear about any places in the middle east.

Comment: I dont know about the middle East but would [Jantar Mantar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jantar_Mantar_(Jaipur)) in India interest you?

Comment: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2074113 seems to have a similar discussion

Comment: Thales also used geometry to calculate height of pyramids in Egypt. In general here's wikipedia's entry on [Mathematics and Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_and_architecture) which discusses usage of fractals in Hindu temples.

Comment: Migrate to Travel.SE?

Comment: I vote against closing this thread: if there was room for "a book every mathematician should read" then I think there's room for "a place every mathematician should visit"... In any case: it was suggested to migrate to travel.SE: is there a significant user base on travel.SE having the mathematical background to answer this question non-trivially?

Comment: Princeton university

Comment: This is a little different than the other answers, but if it's easy to get to, maybe the Museum of Mathematics in New York?

Answer (score 6):

For sake of pure history associated with Göttingen it should be a Mecca for any mathematicians. I also remember once my Calculus professor talk about an auditorium for acoustics where if you whisper at one end and if your friend is standing at the foci, then she can hear you. (This [blog](http://buildz.blogspot.com/2011/02/sister-ray-trace.html) discusses it a bit.)

As far as architecture inspired by mathematics:

- Double spiral staircase in Vatican as mentioned by the visitor [here](http://hyperbolic-crochet.blogspot.com/2010/04/talk-i-missed.html)

  [image]
- [Islamic designs of geometry](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/math5.pattern/lesson5math.html) as well as [Alhambra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhambra)
- This [site](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/math-art-arch.shtml#Pyramids) also poses the interesting question: *Why are fortresses often pentagons?*

However, the go-to-guide would be Jane Burry's [The New Mathematics of Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0500342644) ([Google images of some of its content](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=mOc&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=the%20new%20mathematics%20of%20architecture&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4732l5072l1l5472l3l3l0l0l0l2l273l777l2-3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=861&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=zQ8RT-DnIJTciQKR2s2yDQ#um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=P4w&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&authuser=0&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=the%20new%20mathematics%20of%20architecture&oq=the%20new%20mathematics%20of%20architecture&aq=f&aqi=g1g-S4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=35395l36469l0l36700l2l2l0l0l0l0l189l369l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=954d6c374ef251d&biw=1280&bih=861))

Answer (score 4):

See the [Mathematical Tourist](http://www.maa.org/mathtourist/mathtourist.html) column, by Ivars Peterson, at the MAA site, for a large number of suggestions.

See also Alexander Hahn's book, Mathematical Excursions to the World's Great Buildings, https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691145204/mathematical-excursions-to-the-worlds-great-buildings

Comment: Updated link [here](https://maa.org/the-mathematical-tourist)